# Navigating to a web view in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to navigate to a web view from my react-native app. When I click a button, I want to redirect to this web view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native' 
// ...
// ...
onPress = (url) => {
    Linking.openURL(url)
}
```

This will open a browser for users. or you can do this with a Modal and a WebView Component:

```
import {Modal, WebView} from 'react-native'
// ...
// ...
onPress = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: true })
}
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPress('https://google.com')}>
                <Text>Open</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <Modal visible={this.state.isVisible} transparent={false}>
                 <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                     <WebView source={{uri: this.state.url}} />
                 </View>
             </Modal>
        </View>
    )
}
```